# How to find the reference of an object?

Tags: tuleap

In Tuleap ALM I would like to set up references to wiki pages, to documents,... 
For the artifact in a tracker the reference is clearly displayed.
But how (and where) can I find the reference tag of the object (document, wiki page, survey) which is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question https://tuleap.net/doc/en/user-guide/project-admin.html#reference-pattern-configuration?